# Copying Images from URl list to my server all at once by php

Tags: php, loops

I have big list of Urls in html file for images something like this :

```
<a href="http://example.com/image1.jpg">image1</a>
<a href="http://example.com/image2.jpg">image2</a>
<a href="http://example.com/image3.jpg">image3</a>
<a href="http://example.com/image4.jpg">image4</a>
<a href="http://example.com/image5.jpg">image5</a>
<a href="http://example.com/image6.jpg">image6</a>
<a href="http://example.com/image7.jpg">image7</a>
```

**Around 50,000 Image**

I want to make small script that can copy all images to my server so i can have them in :

```
http://Mywebsite.com/images/image1.jpg
http://Mywebsite.com/images/image1.jpg
http://Mywebsite.com/images/image1.jpg
...
```

I want to make loop and each Url in the list must be deleted after the image is copied successfully because sometimes if page crush on loading or something i can continue my loop without overwriting or reading again , if there is a better solution to not overwrite and read the url again please tell me.

Comment: Its not entirely clear to me what you're asking. It might help if you wrote the 'small script' and then we can work out the problems with it.

Comment: I am new in php .. i still didnt made any script yet .. see for example , i want the script to go to Url-list.html and copy image1 to my server then image2 then image3 and so on

Comment: You could read your HTML file into a very simple database table with two fields: path & already_copied. Then you could copy the image files by reading one DB record at a time and update the DB after each successful copy. If you had to restart your program you could query the DB SELECT path FROM TABLE WHERE already_copied == FALSE and resume copying from there.

Comment: thank you for your help , but i am still in new in php and database thing .. Mario post was good for me , coz i understood it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a script that reads your html file line per line. 
You can do that using `fopen` and `fgets`.

```
fopen("path/to/some/file", "r");
while ( ( $line = fgets( $handle ) ) !== false ) 
{
    // do somehting with $line
}
```

*This way the file gets not simply parsed into memory, so you don't have to worry about size*

Then after parsing every line I would write down a lock file containing the current line number / index. So if your script crashes and you restart it the iteration simply skips every line until it's current index is higher than the index from the lock file.

**the script**

It might work but, in the end should not simply copy paste everything. But i hope it helps you finding your solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
// I DID NOT TEST THIS! 
// but it should work.

$handle = fopen("path/to/the/html/file/containing/the/urls.html", "r");
$storage = "path/where/you/want/your/images/";
$lockFile = __DIR__.'/index.lock';
$index = 0;

// get the lock index
if ( !file_exists( $lockFile ) )
{
    file_put_contents( $lockFile, 0 );
}

// load the current index
$start = file_get_contents( $lockFile );

if ( $handle ) 
{
    // line by line step by step
    while ( ( $line = fgets( $handle ) ) !== false ) 
    {
        // update the 
        $index++;

        if ( $start > $index )
        {
            continue;
        }

        // match the url from the element
        preg_match( '/<a href="(.+)">/', $line, $url ); $url = $url[1];

        $file = basename( $url );

        // check if the file already exists 

        if ( !file_exists( $storage.$file )) //edited 
        {
            file_put_contents( $storage.$file, file_get_contents( $url ) );
        }

        // update the lock file
        file_put_contents( $lockFile, $index );
    }

    fclose($handle);
} 
else 
{
    throw new Exception( 'Could not open file.' );
}
```

Comment: You are far more ambitious than me, but this is a strong push in the right direction.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i am looking for .. 1 Q about how long will it take to copy 50K images .. lets say 1 image = 1MB .. coz i would rather download all images by program and upload but it takes time so is this faster ? ..

and thanks for your big help i really appreciate it ..

Comment: It wont make much a diffrence if your "porgramm" is also going to download the files synchronous. You could upgrade that script by creating a lock file for each image, that would allow to spawn multiple workers of that script. That would be ( depending on your connection ) alot faster.

Comment: i tried it its working well :) .. thank you ,, btw u missed 1 " ) " 
on : " if ( !file_exists( $storage.$file ) " it should be  " if ( !file_exists( $storage.$file )) "

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this, of course you should also add here some error checking things :)

```
define("SITE_DIR", '/home/www/temp');

$file = file('in.txt');

foreach ($file AS $row){
    preg_match('/(?<=\")(.*?)(?=\")/', $row, $url);

    $path = parse_url($url[0], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $dirname = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

    if (!is_dir(SITE_DIR . $dirname)){
        mkdir(SITE_DIR . $dirname, 0777, true);
    }

    file_put_contents(SITE_DIR. $path, file_get_contents($url[0]));
}
```